# Journald SystemMaxUse when machine-id changes

Tags: log-rotation, systemd-journald

I am using journald on an embedded system for logging to a persistant drive. The maximum stored logs are limited using the config parameter SystemMaxUse= and log rotation enabled. This works fine, until the [systemd machine-id](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/machine-id.html) changes during software update (we flash a full system image during software update, very typical in embedded systems).

With the new machine-id journald creates a new log folder name, and ignores all previous folders. Hence the rotation mechanism ignores logs from other machine-id's and my quota is exceeded.

Does anybody know, how to include other machine-id logs into journald log rotation? Thanks...

Side note:
With journalctl --merge I can read logs from other machine-id stored in the same journald log path, however the --merge option is ignored with cleanup commands like `journalctl --rotate` and/or `jorunalctl --vacuumsize=1G`

Comment: I was looking into hardcoding the machine-id into the device image from factory, so that it stays constant over software updates. However this would imply the same machine-id in the full product line. This is discouraged by systemd, see for example:
https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/9609

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @Kreuzade unfortunately not. As mitigation I erase all journald logs when running a software update. Quota over logs unfortunately on embedded devices with limited storage and unsupervised operations.

Comment: Maybe this is a solution...?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68744130/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-link-for-the-machine-id-without-modifying-yocto/68779616#68779616

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is so late but i have encountred exactly the same issue, the solution that i came with is: at the end of OS update i rename the existing log folders with the new machine-id, now i have no issue with that and old logs are taken into account when system rotate

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Until now I am mitigating this problem by manually erasing all log folders from unknown machine-id folders, but renaming and keeping would be way cooler!

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what @amer answered, another solution is that during software update you copy the systemd machine-id file to the new installed system, thus keeping the ID unchanged.

This can easily be done in a postinstall step or hook. Such hooks are supported by most software update frameworks, in my case rauc.